# Trouble listing collections in mongodb using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having issues listing the collections in my mongodb via node. To setup mongo I did the following:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@4.2
brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
```

I then created a database and collection like so:

```
mongo
use mongo-crud
db.createCollection('dogs')
```

I can see via the command line that the database and the collection were successfully created. Now my node app is like so:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
// Assert is not really needed though we can use it to check for errors
const assert = require('assert');

// Note that this is the default port that must be used
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

const dbName = 'mongo-crud';

// useUnifiedTopology is needed to hide a warning
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);
  db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collInfos) {
    console.log(err)
    assert.equal(err, null);
  });

  client.close();
});
```

There doesn't seem to be an issue connection to the database but when I try to list the collections it throws an error `name: 'MongoError' [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you also include the ```codeName``` of the error in your question? Or maybe the complete error if possible.

Comment: how do I log that? sorry fairlt new to js and node

Comment: It should automatically be logged alongside the error you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't wait for listing collections and the connection closes immediately before executing `db.listCollections()` completely. You can change the connect method to below:

```
client.connect(async (err) => {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    try {
        const collections = await db.listCollections().toArray()
        console.log(collections)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    client.close();
});
```

Comment: Damn, missed that. It’s asynchronous so closes before if finishes. Thanks.